# How to allocate memory properly in Keras [Memory allocation error]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

So im trying to solve Kaggle's melanoma contest and i keep getting this error when trying to run a simple keras conv model:

```
Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20,128,1022,1022] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Initially i was trying to use 33k images and about 6 layers (little did i knew ill have this kind of error). Then i said okay after all these images are 1024x1024 i'm gonna lower layers and unit inside for easier computation, but problem persisted, i wasnt been able to pass not even the first epoch.

Then i said okay im gonna create a new directory with only 600 images for training and 200 for validation (How could this problem persist right??). Well it continued, i came to realize that maybe the problem is my pc configuration. I have Ubuntu 20 and i checked that my GPU was being used, actually every time i run the code at the beginning terminal says:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-06-03 13:48:35.960461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-06-03 13:48:35.994757: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-06-03 13:48:35.995140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.56GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 3.82GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 119.24GiB/s
```

I dont know if maybe i configured something wrong, i had no problems when doing easy codes like digit recognizer and cats and dogs (those images were 28*28 and 256*256) with 10k + images...

My code looks like this so far (after changing model for easy computation):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPool2D
model = models.Model()
// Capas

input_layer = Input(shape = (1024,1024,3),dtype = 'float32')
conv1 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu')(input_layer)
maxpool1 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu',dtype = 'float32')(maxpool1)
// All layers below until next comment are commented for taking load from cpu
maxpool2 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu',dtype = 'float32')(maxpool2)
maxpool3 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',dtype = 'float32')(maxpool3)
maxpool4 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',dtype = 'float32')(maxpool4)
maxpool5 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv5)
conv6 = Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation = 'relu',dtype = 'float32')(maxpool5)
// Here stops the commenting of lines
flatten = Flatten()(conv2)
dense1 = Dense(64,activation = 'relu')(flatten)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)

 Generating model

model = models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = output_layer)

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

 All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        # This is the target directory
        train_dir,
        # All images will be resized to 150x150
        target_size=(1024, 1024),
        batch_size=20,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        valid_dir,
        target_size=(1024, 1024),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')


history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=30,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=10)
```

Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed, thanks a lot for taking the time!

Comment: You should downscale the images, 1024x1024 is simply too big. Something like 256x256 is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use TPU
https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/129828

```
# detect and init the TPU
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)

# instantiate a distribution strategy
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)

# instantiating the model in the strategy scope creates the model on the TPU
with tpu_strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential( … ) # define your model normally
    model.compile( … )

# train model normally
model.fit(training_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=…)
```

But size 1024x1024 for kaggle too large.